# Restore a SQL Server database from single instance to cluster

Tags: sql-server-2005

I need to transfer a database from a SQL Server instance test server to a production environment that is clustered. But SQL Server doesn't allow you to use backup/restore to do it from single instance to cluster. I'm talking about a Microsoft CRM complex database here.

Your help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the [Microsoft SQL Server Database Publishing Wizard](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=56E5B1C5-BF17-42E0-A410-371A838E570A):

> SQL Server Database Publishing Wizard
>   enables the deployment of SQL Server
>   databases into a hosted environment on
>   either a SQL Server 2000 or 2005
>   server. It generates a single SQL
>   script file which can be used to
>   recreate a database (both schema and
>   data) in a shared hosting environment
>   where the only connectivity to a
>   server is through a web-based control
>   panel with a script execution window.
>   If supported by the hosting service
>   provider, the Database Publishing
>   Wizard can also directly upload
>   databases to servers located at the
>   shared hosting provider.
>
> Optionally, SQL Server Database
>   Publishing Wizard can integrate
>   directly into Visual Studio 2005
>   and/or Visual Web Developer 2005
>   allowing easy publishing of databases
>   from within the development
>   environment.

You don't have to use the server-side piece; the client-side 'create a script' piece is generally enough.